# How to Random generate a value like this 23-4564567

Tags: java, string, random

I am looking for how I can random generate a value like this 23-3455673. My issue is I'm not sure how to get the - in the middle of my random numeric code.
I am using a Maven java project and using the `RandomStringUtils.randomnumeric(10)`

So looking for a way to random generate the value as 23-5672345 basically two digits then a - then 7 digits all in a single string.

I'm not super skilled here so i really am not looking for highly technical answers just the simplest method to make this work is what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for any advise on how to accomplish this.

Comment: What do you mean by "in Maven"? Where have you put this code, and where does the result appear? See also [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generate a `String` with length `9`, then insert `-` at index `2`:

```
String nineDigit = RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(9);
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(nineDigit);
String result = stringBuilder.insert(2, "-").toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Why should I handle that? I think leading zeros are legal and the generated result is not a number, it's a string.

Comment: Thank you sir this did the trick for my test thanks again for the knowledge! much appricated

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "in maven" but as you are using  `RandomStringUtils.randomnumeric(10)` you can use

```
 StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder(RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(2)).append("-").append(RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(7))
 String result=sb.toString()
 System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without third party libraries :

1) The easy solution : generate 2 digits, then append `-` then generate 7 digits :

```
Random random = new Random();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//Append a number between [0; 10[
sb.append(random.nextInt(10));
sb.append(random.nextInt(10));
sb.append('-');
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    sb.append(random.nextInt(10));
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Output :

> 77-5711939

2) The concise solution : generate a 9 digits string.

```
random.nextInt(1_000_000_000)
```

but if the generated value is less than `100_000_000`, you are not guaranteed to have 9 digits. Hence, you will pad the value with `String.format()` :

```
// %09d imposes 9 digits. 0 are added if necessary.
// String.format("%09d", 42) returns 000000042
String result = String.format("%09d", random.nextInt(1_000_000_000));
```

Then you can insert a `-` at the 2nd position.